# OpenGL in Delphi - 16 bit texture displaying

Tags: delphi, opengl

I have an problem and I have no idea to beat this.
I'm loading a 16-bit monochromatic texture from a TIFF image into memory, then I upload this texture into an OpenGL texture. It works correctly. But I want to have two parameters - an X1 and X2 integers from range 0..65535, where: values lower than X1 are presented as black, and values higher than X2 are white, and values between X1 and X2 are scaled into a bit depth of monitor (commonly 8 bits).
How I can do it using OpenGL? I have made it by GDI but it works slow for high resolution images.

There are codes in Delphi where I init OpenGL and load an texture.

Creating form (on beginning):

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  DC:HDC;
  RC:HGLRC;
begin
  OsX:=0;
  OsY:=0;
  OsZ:=-5;
  Obrot:=0;

  // for Open GL
  DC:=GetDC(Panel1.Handle);
  SetupPixelFormat(DC);  //pixel format setting up
  RC:=wglCreateContext(DC);  //makes OpenGL window out of DC
  wglMakeCurrent(DC, RC);    //makes OpenGL window active
  GLInit; //calling opengl init
end;
```

Setting up a pixel format:

```
procedure TForm1.setupPixelFormat(DC:HDC);
const
    pfd:TPIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR = (
        nSize:sizeof(TPIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR); 
        nVersion:1; 
        dwFlags:PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL or PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW or PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
        iPixelType:PFD_TYPE_RGBA; 
        cColorBits:24; 
        cRedBits:0;
        cRedShift:0;
        cGreenBits:0; 
        cGreenShift:0; 
        cBlueBits:0;
        cBlueShift:0;
        cAlphaBits:0;
        cAlphaShift:0;
        cAccumBits: 0;
        cAccumRedBits: 0; 
        cAccumGreenBits: 0;
        cAccumBlueBits: 0;
        cAccumAlphaBits: 0; 
        cDepthBits:16; 
        cStencilBits:0; 
        cAuxBuffers:0; 
        iLayerType:PFD_MAIN_PLANE; 
        bReserved: 0;
        dwLayerMask: 0; 
        dwVisibleMask: 0;
        dwDamageMask: 0; 
   );
var
  pixelFormat : integer;
begin
  pixelFormat := ChoosePixelFormat(DC, @pfd);
  if (pixelFormat = 0) then exit;
  if (SetPixelFormat(DC, pixelFormat, @pfd) <> TRUE) then exit;
end;
```

OpenGL initialization:

```
procedure TForm1.GLInit();
var
  Tablica:PTablica2Word; //pointer to an array of Word of Word
  Tab:PTablica1Word; //pointer to an array of Word
  Wys,Szer:Cardinal; //Width and Height of loaded image
  pData:Pointer;
  p:Pointer;
  i,j:Integer;
  Krok:Cardinal;
begin
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glFrustum(-0.1, 0.1, -0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 25.0);
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

  //loading a 16-bit texture from 3.tiff file
  New(Tablica);
  TIFFForm.LoadFile('3.tiff',Tablica,True); //loading an image
  TablicaRozmiar(Tablica,Szer,Wys); //getting an Width and Height of loaded image

  New(Tab);
  SetLength(Tab.Dane,Szer*Wys);
  Krok:=0;
  //dropping loaded data to buffer Tab (pointer)
  For i:=0 to Wys-1 do
  Begin
    For j:=0 to Szer-1 do
    Begin
      Tab.Dane[Krok]:=Tablica.Dane[j,i];
      Inc(Krok);
    End;
  End;
  //assigning pointer
  pData:=Pointer(@Tab.Dane[0]);
  CreateTexture(Szer,Wys,pData); //creating an texture from loaded image
  Dispose(Tab);
  Dispose(Tablica);    

  Draw();
end;
```

Creating texture:

```
function TForm1.CreateTexture(Width,Height:Word;pData:Pointer):Cardinal;
Begin
  glGenTextures(1, Texture);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Texture);
  glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

  Result:=gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_LUMINANCE16, Width, Height, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, pData); //putting an loaded 16-bit image into opengl texture

end;
```

Drawing:

```
procedure TForm1.Draw();
begin
  Application.ProcessMessages;

  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT or GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  glLoadIdentity();

  glTranslatef(OsX,0,0);
  glTranslatef(0,OsY,0);
  glTranslatef(0,0,OsZ);

  glRotate(Obrot,0,1,0);

  glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
  glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

  glTexGenf(GL_S, GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE, GL_SPHERE_MAP);
  glTexGenf(GL_T, GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE, GL_SPHERE_MAP);


  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);


  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Texture);

  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    // Front Face
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(-1.0, -1.0,  0.0);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0); glVertex3f( 1.0, -1.0,  0.0);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0); glVertex3f( 1.0,  1.0,  0.0);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0); glVertex3f(-1.0,  1.0,  0.0);
  glEnd();

  SwapBuffers(wglGetCurrentDC);
end;
```

Thank for any suggestion :)

There is a part of GDI drawing using Graphics32 and Scanline:

```
TablicaRozmiar(ai_TablicaDraw,Szer,Wys); //getting Width and Height of data
Bitmapa.Width:=Szer; //setting up virtual TBitmap32 Width
Bitmapa.Height:=Wys; //setting up virtual TBitmap32 Height
KolorMakeTable; //making a table of colour - scalling from 16bit to 8 bit display, using X1 and X2 values
For i:=0 to Wys-1 do //making a scanline
Begin
  abi_Punkty:=Bitmapa.ScanLine[i]; //abi_Punkty:PColor32Array
  For j:=0 to Szer-1 do
  Begin
    abi_Punkty[j]:=((KolorTableR[ai_TablicaDraw.Dane[j,i]] shl 8) + KolorTableG[ai_TablicaDraw.Dane[j,i]]) shl 8 + KolorTableB[ai_TablicaDraw.Dane[j,i]]; //putting a grayscale color
  End;
End;
```

Comment: I did not find a code you are currently using (the slow one)?

Comment: I have put all code in post. So I wonder how you cannot see the code?

Comment: I think adlabac means the GDI version you wrote.

Comment: Oh i understood it wrong... The GDI way is difficult and there are two threads: one for mini map, second for full size image. It is based on Graphics32 and scanline. I want to make it faster and I think that is only one way - OpenGL... But how to make it?

Comment: Hmm, ScanLine is good. Are you sure it cannot be optimized? Can you post just that piece of code?

Comment: Scanline is funny also but when we have now Full HD displays it works slow because there is more pixels. I will give a small piece of code soon but I really want to make it in OpenGL.

Comment: I've put a part of GDI drawing code on bottom. But I think that there is no special way to get a lot faster work than OpenGL - I have a graphic station...

Comment: Sorry, only now I noticed that you added ScanLine code. Several questions: - Are you calling KolorMakeTable procedure allwas, or only once, uring the initialiyation process? - What is the pixel depth (I guess 32 bits)? - How bif is KolorTableR matrix: 65536^2, (X2-X1)^2 or something else? - ScanLine element is 8-bit, not 32-bit as you are populating it now (it has Szer*4 elements for 32-bit mode).

Comment: Hello, 1. KolorMakeTable is an array [0..65535] of Byte - it returns a Byte colour of an Word index (input data is Word, 16-bit). It's called LookUpTable (LUT) and it reduces time of calculating. Pixel depth of screen is 32 bit (as Graphics32). Scanline is 8 bit element but I have used a PColor32Array and it is a pointer. It works well, but I want to look a OpenGL Shader way...